# Fastest and cleanest way to load a FileSystem entry into a memory-mapped file (NIO2)

Tags: java, filesystems, in-memory, nio2

I'd like to extract a zip/jar entry into memory so I can close the zip stream/FS and keep the file in the JVM without dealing with temporary copies.

One option is to use Files.readAllLines(Path pathToZipFSentry), but it seems it used a buffered reader which can penalize a lot for big files.

So I am researching how to do it in Java NIO2 and it seems the way is ending with a MappedByteBuffer through FileChannels.

I cannot use the RandomAccessFile.getChannel() as I come from a Path of a virtual FileSystem, not a literal File.
I cannot use Files.newByteChannel(rscPath, StandardOpenOption.READ) and then (fileChannel.)map() because it returns a  SeekableByteChannel which doesn't got map in the interface...

Is thee any one/two high level liners for this by means of Path(s)/File(s)/FileSystem(s)/FileChannel(s) in Java8? I would expect something like InMemoryFile file = Files.loadIntoMem(Path) I've been 1 hour looking for a  close option...

Comment: Have you tried and `FileChannel.open()`? But anyway, this will not solve the problem that you cannot directly mmap() from a zip entry in any case; there _will_ be a temporary copy somewhere

Comment: That's precisely the approach I'm going through now and the exact fear I am getting while I am advancing, but I feel ilike it must be an easier option somwehere

Comment: By the way, confirmed, com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.map() returns a NotSupportedoperationException();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really load this directly into memory.

You do have `FileChannel.open()` from which you can then `.map()` but that will create a temporary entry on your disk anyway.

There is also [memoryfilesystem](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem), but it will not handle files big enough for it to be useful, unfortunately.

The best solution I see is to `Files.copy()` into a temporary file and mmap() that; then copy back to the zip file when you're done with the modifications.

But basically, this is what you already do, so...

Comment: I am interested in the "that will create a temporary entry" on your disk... Shouldn't map from 0 to size() do a 100% in-memory loading on a MappedByteBuffer?

Comment: That is unlikely for the simple reason that a zip entry is sequential by definition; for `*Stream`s, that is a different story however. But mappings are, well, random access.

Comment: Do you mean that the temporal file is needed BEFORE the complete loading or that it is needed after load operation?